# theme node add use custom theme

Tags: 6, theming

I followed this answer to try and theme node add

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538600/how-can-i-theme-the-template-for-edit-or-add-a-node-for-a-specific-content-type

the only problem is my theme is using Garland in node/add so I can not theme it with mythemename_, how do I use my custom theme for this instead of garland

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have enabled your Administration Theme for content creation.

Check `www.yoursite.com/admin/settings/admin`:

[image]

and see if that check box is checked.  If it is, uncheck it and then your custom theme should be used from then on, assuming, of course, it's enabled for the user.